# How to connect RDS with phpmyadmin - AWS

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin, amazon-rds

I am new to Amazon Web Services. I want to import my `.sql` file to phpmyadmin. `EC2` and `RDS` instsnces are launched succesfully. Now How can I get newly created `db` in `phpmyadmin`?

I have searched on that and got some blogs and solution and as per those have added `IP` address of server on which my `phpMyAdmin` is installed. Now I don't know the furthe procedure. Can anyone please help me?

I tried to update `etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf` but I don't have permission to access that file. How can I get permission for that? Do I need to create `IAM user`?

Answer (score 0):

Best installation tutorial I've seen on this came from Andrew Puch on Github.  Just google Andrew Puch and github and you'll find the installation procedures laid out for you, and he did a Youtube video on the subject as well.

As for the rest of it, it is a tangle of server settings and parameter group settings that I have yet to figure out. if anyone else has got a handle on it, I would be eager to find out.